# Ansible merge 2 arrays

Tags: json, ansible

I am trying to merge the following 2 arrays using Ansible:

```
TASK [Show var1] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var1": [
        {
            "id": "133"
        },
        {
            "id": "149"
        },
        {
            "id": "188"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
TASK [Show var2] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var2": [
        {
            "name": "two"
        },
        {
            "name": "one"
        },
        {
            "name": "three"
        }
    ]
}
```

The result should be:

```
    "var1": [
        {
            "id": "133",
            "name": "two"
        },
        {
            "id": "149",
            "name": "one"
        },
        {
            "id": "188",
            "name": "three"
        }
    ]
```

My efforts for merging so far...returned only the last pair. How can I get the whole arrays merged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible solution; we use `set_fact` and the `combine` filter, looping over `var1|zip(var2)`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    var1:
      - id: 133
      - id: 149
      - id: 188
    var2:
      - name: two
      - name: one
      - name: three

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        var3: "{{ var3 + [item[0]|combine(item[1])] }}"
      vars:
        var3: []
      loop: "{{ var1|zip(var2)|list }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ var3 }}"
```

(See the docs for information about [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) and [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries)).

This will output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'id': 133}, {'name': 'two'}])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'id': 149}, {'name': 'one'}])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'id': 188}, {'name': 'three'}])

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": 133,
            "name": "two"
        },
        {
            "id": 149,
            "name": "one"
        },
        {
            "id": 188,
            "name": "three"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you! By the way...can this be made "on the fly"? E.g. var2 is generated as follows:
      set_fact:
        var2: "{{ var2|default([]) + [ {'name': item.matches[0].value} ] }}"
      with_items: "{{ output.results }}"
Could var3 get generated here?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting, but Ansible doesn't care if a variable is defined statically or created at runtime using `set_fact`. It might be best to open a new question, because then you can show the code you're working with.